# Blackberry http connection problem

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

My app uses an http connection to a server.
On the 9550 BlackBerry simulator, it runs fine but when I run it on an 8520 simulator it gives the error

> java.io.IOException:Tunnel Failed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: These are two distinct questions - it would be better to ask the database question separately.

Comment: thanks for your advise, i m going to edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these StackOverflow topics:
[Tunnel Failed, BlackBerry Curve 8900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362545/tunnel-failed-blackberry-curve-8900)
[Are socket connections faster than http on Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286206/are-socket-connections-faster-than-http-on-blackberry).

Comment: thanks..as i write deviceside=true.my problem get solved. but is this will work in each situation??